# Rails Simple_form show form validation errors on load the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Well i am new to rails and i'm trying to make a form inside a modal at the index action which is working great except on opening this modal i find all the required inputs in the form colored in red , which is confusing because i didn't clicked the submit button yet to check for validation as you can see in the screenshot , so what i'm doing wrong here ? any help is appreciated

[image: this is the modal form]

this is the modal partial in the index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'popup' %>
```

here is _popup.html.erb

```
<% content_for :popup do %>
<%- model_class = Supplier -%>
 <div class="modal splash fade" id="splash" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1><%= t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>           
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

this is the _form.htm.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@supplier ,remote: true) do |f| %> 
 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :code %>
  <%= f.input :email , :hint => "should be a valid email "%>
  <%= f.input :status %>
  <%= f.input :total_credit %>
  <%= f.input :user_id,collection: [] || User.all ,label_method: :name , value_method: :id ,include_blank: true %>
  <%= f.input :notes %>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

and the controller action :index

```
def index
 @suppliers  = Supplier.all
 @supplier   = Supplier.new
end
```

here is my model :

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :supplier_branches
has_many :supplier_phones
has_many :supplier_contacts
has_many :purchase_invoices
belongs_to :user

validates :name,:code, presence: true
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }

end
```

Comment: Can you share your `Supplier` model. Thanks.

Comment: Its because of this `validates :name,:code, presence: true` the form helper makes it red because its mandatory to fill in those. If you dont want that then you can use `f.label` and `f.text_field`. This will give you power on your labels.

Comment: yes that is correct but it should do that after i submit the form with blank inputs right ? @HarryBomrah

Comment: try add `<%= f.input :name, required: false %>`

Comment: Well form helper might be putting a class in the mandatory fields. That class might have red color in your css or you can override that class in your css and make it black.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I believe doing so, the form will not validate `name` field.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk it did remove the red color , but this wont remove the validation of the form !!?

Comment: Same doubt here, how do you keep the validation working, but not on page load?? I want the validation to be made, but when losing focus, or when submiting.... not on load! Of course in an empty form will be empty required fields, do'h! I don't want to tell my user he's forgetting something before he actually forget it.

Comment: @AlexLoop i'm using Parsley it is a JavaScript form validation library